# How to check which span tag is currently active

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have two span tags in main anchor tag,with 2 different class names as below.

```
<a class="clickSlide" id="btnmain_login" href="/">
    <span class="Icohide"></span>
    <span class="Icoactive"></span>
</a>
```

When logged in, span with `Icoactive` class will be active, when not logged in span with `Icohide` class will be active. How to check which span class is currently active in JQuery.

Please help.

Comment: `$('span.Icoactive')` should return the span that has the active class

Comment: Please define `active span`? Will have attribute/special class or what?

Comment: This also smells like an XY problem, I hope what you are trying to achieve is no to check if the user is logged in, because it's easy to edit the HTML via developper tools

Answer (score 0):

Just select all `span` elements and use [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method which takes class as parameter to search which one has active class.

### Here is an example

```js
console.log($('span.Icoactive').hasClass('active')) // will return false
console.log($('span.Icohide').hasClass('active')) // will return true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="clickSlide" id="btnmain_login" href="/">
  <span class="Icohide active"></span>
  <span class="Icoactive"></span>
</a>
```

> or

```js
$("span").each(function(index, element) {
  console.log(element.className);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="clickSlide" id="btnmain_login" href="/">
  <span class="Icohide active"></span>
  <span class="Icoactive"></span>
</a>
```